# How to connect Nikken counter-top water filter beneath the counter

Tags: water, filter

I have Nikken counter-top water filter system.
Exactly like this one: 
http://www.ebay.com/itm/Nikken-PiMag-Water-Filtration-System-/161652322514

I am moving to a newly build house and need to install this water filter beneath the counter. So my plan is to connect the incoming filter line to the cold water supply 1/2" T-connector under the counter and then install a separate drinking water faucet and connect the output filter line to that drinking water faucet.

Currently the 1/4 filter hoses are attached to the diverter which has the single-barb style connection with the compression fitting screwed on top. The thread of the compression nut is not NPT standard. Nikken water diverter looks exactly like this one: 
http://www.curezone.org/blogs/fm.asp?i=1824643

The local hardware stores and even the specialized plumbing stores are unable to come up with the suitable fittings to allow the proposed connection.

Any idea where can I find say 1/2" male to 1/8" barb with compression fittings?
Or may be somebody can suggest other solutions to my problem?